# HTML - inline tags not refelecting

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a page where it loads some values from a spreadsheet, and displays the values on the page. (i.e. so it can handle multiple languages).

**Problem**

When I put html tags in the spreadsheet, they are not applied.

**Example**

If I put the following text in an html file and view it, the browser applies the html tags as expected.

```
<div><a href='http://...'>some <br> value</a></div>
```

[image]

However, when it is applied loaded from the spreadsheet, the `<br>` tag is not applied and it stays on one line.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">
    <a ui-sref="open.registration.login.resetPassword"
        class="bmw-command-link bmw-mt-2 bmw-mb-2">{{ 'gcdm-login.forgotten_password' |
        translate }}</a>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Also, if I update the value in Chromes Developer tools, the value changes in the browser, but html tags are not applied.  It is as if the browsers display does not refresh to apply html tags.

**Question**

Is there a way I can get the html tags read in from the spreadsheet applied?

Is this a timing issue, meaning that the DOM is rendered already and cannot be changed on the fly?

Thanks

Comment: `However, when it is applied loaded from the spreadsheet` ... you mean when adding the code from inspect element itself? If yes the reason why the `<br>` is not applied is because you edit the element text. You should edit it as `HTML` and add the `<br>`. Now you should see the expected output.

Comment: @lonut both - when it is applied from the spreadsheet and when I change it when inspecting the element, the <br> is not applied.

Comment: What's the ``spreadsheet``?

Comment: @Richard, ok then at least for the inspect element part the second part of my abbove comment should explain what you're doing wrong. Right click on the tag in inspect element and you shoud see something like `Edit as HTML`. Add your `<br>` tag after clicking that button and you will see the break.

Comment: `<br>` is escaped. There will be probably filter to print safe string..

Comment: @Alexander the spreadsheet is applied to the html with Angular Interpolation and data-binding

Comment: @Richard Sir did you tried this way?? `<br/>`

Comment: @Empty Brain - yes, it still just displays the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what version of Angular you use, but for all it resumes to one thing: you have to bind your text as HTML by using either `ng-bind-html` directive or `[innerHTML]` property.

**AngularJS**:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">
    <a ui-sref="open.registration.login.resetPassword"
        class="bmw-command-link bmw-mt-2 bmw-mb-2" ng-bind-html="'gcdm-login.forgotten_password' | translate"></a>
</div>
```

**Angular 2-6**:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">
    <a ui-sref="open.registration.login.resetPassword"
        class="bmw-command-link bmw-mt-2 bmw-mb-2" [innerHTML]="'gcdm-login.forgotten_password' | translate"></a>
</div>
```

I've also made you an working example **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/y3xmr8j1p1)**.

Answer (score 0):

its work fine

try this

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">
  <a ui-sref="open.registration.login.resetPassword" class="bmw-command-link bmw-mt-2 bmw-mb-2">forgotten<br>password</a>
</div>
```